# Authenticating googleapi node library with passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using passport for google oauth, I want to use it to make API calls as well. All of the googleapi documentation revolves around using google's own authentication library instead.

In particular, what is contained in the auth object, as seen in the calednar.events.list call at the end of the quickstart, and how do I get it out of passport?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

`auth` in this context is `OAuth2` object. You can see how it is handled in each request from [the googleapis source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/lib/apirequest.ts#L79-L81). For instance, you could have set in at the context scope like the following :

```
google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client
})
```

or in each request like in the getting started sample code.

---

As you want to use it for passport, I guess you will have something like the following, assuming `/auth/google` is the auth endpoint :

```
function userLogged(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/auth/google');
}

app.get('/calendarList', userLogged, function(req, res) {

    // req.user is the login user

    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
        config.clientID,
        config.clientSecret,
        config.callbackURL
    );

    oauth2Client.credentials = {
        access_token: req.user.access_token,
        refresh_token: req.user.refresh_token
    };

    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    calendar.events.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, response) {
        // process result
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the [desired scopes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) for access to the Google Calendar API.

-jim